# How to get a unique highscore per user

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

I have the following tables: *users*, *highscores*

I would like to get the top ten best results in *highscore*. The scores should be unique, meaning **one score per user**. I tried using `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP` but this is not returning the correct data. I get the correct uid, score, alias and email but the time is not correct. It seems that it is taken from another highscore post. How do I get the correct data? As soon as we find the "best score" I want everything else (time) from the exact same post.

```
SELECT UID, ALIAS, EMAIL, SCORE, TIME
FROM users t
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_uid, MAX(score) as SCORE, value1 as TIME
            FROM highscores
            GROUP BY user_uid) x
  ON x.user_uid = t.uid
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Which RDBMS????

Comment: RDBMS: I use MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the time from the highscores table separately
MySQL doesn't respect ANSI standard aggregations [by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by): hence your dodgy data

```
SELECT 
    u.UID, u.ALIAS, u.EMAIL, h.SCORE, h.value1 AS TIME
FROM 
   (
    SELECT user_uid, MAX(score) as SCORE
    FROM highscores
    GROUP BY user_uid
   ) x
   JOIN
   highscores h ON x.user_uid = h.user_uid AND x.SCORE = h.SCORE
   JOIN
   users u ON h.user_uid = u.uid
ORDER BY h.SCORE DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This assumes that each user does not have multiple high scores with the same value.
If you do, you need a 2nd derived table with an aggregate to nest the x/h JOIN

Comment: Thanks! And this way I am sure that TIME is collected from the same "post" as SCORE? What if there are more values? Like value2, value3? And what happens if the user has two highscores with the same value?